# Show that $G(x)<0<F(x)$ using the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

$F(x) = \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x+1}$

$G(x) = \ln(x+1)-\ln(x)-\frac{1}{x}$

$x \in ]0, +\infty[$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By the mean value theorem, there exists some $c \in [x, x+1]$ such that
$$\frac{\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)}{1} = \frac{d}{dt} \ln(t)|_{t=c} = \frac{1}{c}.$$
Now compare $\frac{1}{c}$ to $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x+1}$.